# Javascript login Gmail from a API

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want to design a API where i will fill my email id and password and throw that page i can directly login to my gmail account.

For Example I want to do following steps.

1. Open http://gmail.com
2. Wait for some amount of time
3. Fill ID and password field using document.getElementById() by the value i have entered in my API
4. Click the "Sign In" button to enter my Gmail account.

Please help me with the code to do this.

Answer (score 2):

use the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#usernamefield").val('My.Username');
     $("#passwordfield").val('My.Password');
     $("#loginbutton").click();
});
```

Comment: @Kumar "Please give complete piece of code" is like saying "Please do my work for me". By the way, you're not going to be able to run JS under gmail.com under normal circumstances.

Comment: @JuanMendes In this case it was needed to complete my answer. If the code is running from a plug-in, it will work just fine.